# Relation between the surface area of two shapes.

Tags: matrices, plane-geometry, transformational-geometry

I was deepening about figure transformations described by matrices, and I encountered an issue that I wasn't able to solve by myself.

In similar shapes you have a constant linear factor k s.t. 
$$k = \frac{A'B'}{AB}$$ 
where apices means the image of the point for the similitude:
$$T(A) = A'\,or\,\,T(x_A, y_A) = (x'_A, y'_A)$$
Where T represents the transformation function.

Now, the similitude can be described like:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x'\\
y'\\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
a, b\\
-b, a\\
\end{pmatrix} *
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\end{pmatrix} + 
\begin{pmatrix}
e\\
f\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

In this case, it is easy to see that the linear factor is the square root of the surface factor, which is the determinant of the matrix:
$$
k^2 = \begin{vmatrix}a,b\\-b,a\\\end{vmatrix}
$$

This can be easily proved, but in my resource it was written (without explanation or proof) that this is a particular case of a more general one:

> $$\frac{Surface(S')}{Surface(S)} = \begin{vmatrix}a,b\\c,d\\\end{vmatrix}$$

Where Surface is an hypotetically surface calcolator function and S and S' are the two surfaces, with $$ T(S)=S'$$
while a, b, c, d are the coefficient of the affinity defined as:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x'\\
y'\\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
a, b\\
c, d\\
\end{pmatrix} *
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\end{pmatrix} + 
\begin{pmatrix}
e\\
f\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

My question is:

> Is it true? A complete answer would contain a clear proof, maybe also with an intuitive one. If this is not the case, a counter-example would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$, $B$, $C$ are three points in the plane, then you can check that the signed area of triangle $ABC$ is given by:
$$
2\ Area(ABC)=|A,B|+|B,C|+|C,A|,
\quad\hbox{where:}\quad 
|A,B|=\det\pmatrix{x_A & x_B\\ y_A & y_B},\ 
\hbox{and so on.}
$$
If $A'=TA$ etc., where $T$ is some matrix, it follows that:
$$
\begin{align}
2\ Area(A'B'C')&=|A',B'|+|B',C'|+|C',A'|\\
&=|TA,TB|+|TB,TC|+|TC,TA|\\
&=|T||A,B|+|T||B,C|+|T||C,A|\\
&=2\ |T|\ Area(ABC).
\end{align}
$$
As any polygon can be decomposed into triangles, this completes the proof.

Comment: This is great! Just, shouldn't be the following?$$\frac{1}{2}*\begin{vmatrix}A,B\end{vmatrix}..$$

Comment: If so, then I got it and I mark as accepted the answer, otherwise can you link me some reference of why not?

Comment: Of course you are right, I forgot a $1/2$ factor: I'll correct in a moment.